# Wie sagt man »story time« auf Deutsch?

Tags: phrase

Wenn man Bücher für Kinder liest, kann man das auf Englisch »Story Time« nennen.

What is the natural translation of this phrase into German?

I am ready to settle on "Märchenstunde", but want human feedback.

Comment: Yeah "Märchenstunde" is a possibility but some old fashioned word. Maybe you can use this phrase "[Es ist] Zeit für Geschichten" '[It is] time for some stories'. That would come close to Story Time. Or just ask whether the kids want to listen to some stories. That is actually a better way in my perspective because you give them the opportunity to say yes or no. But this should not be an adulting advice. Oh btw if you want to use Märchenstunde when writing or translating texts or books it will totally fit. It is more about to distinguish between written and talking about it.

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel: The term »Märchenstunde« never before was used so frequently like now. This is not what I would call »old fashioned«. Please have a look at the Ngram in my answer: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/35235/1487

Comment: It's *Märchenstunde* but as there are a lot of non-fairytale books for children out in the wild, the term **Vorlesestunde** had become common, too.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast yes I know I looked it up as well but as Janka also mentioned it is not only about "Märchen" anymore. Former I tried to say that Märchenstunde is used more in a written form than it is said. Ngram ist just scanning/ taking articles books etc in perspective.

Comment: Martin, could you define the context, please? I have a hunch that you might need a more case-by-case answer than a simple one-fits-all suggestion.

Comment: *Zeit zum Vorlesen* oder *<Name> liest euch noch etwas vor* sind halbwegs gängig und schränken weder die Tageszeit noch den Lesestoff ein.

Comment: Stephie has a very good point.  Story Time at home won't be expressed the same as Story Time at the public library.  What was your context, Martin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although *Märchenstunde* is a more direct translation of *story time* and not  bound to a specific time of day, *Gutenachtgeschichte*, in its various ways of writing exceeds the *Märchenstunde* usage by far. It does, however, refer to the last story of the day that children would be listening to in bed.

Even if it is not a 100% translation, I think it needs mentioning here. **My** kids always had a *Gutenachtgeschichte* rather than a *Märchenstunde*.

[image]

Comment: But if a bookshop or library offers "story time" events, that's definitively not a "Gutenachtgeschichte". The context may require something different.

Comment: Auch morgens um 11:00 im Kindergarten ist es keine Gutenachtgeschichte. Und sicher keine Gute - Nacht - Geschichte.

Comment: But *Gutenachtgeschichte* denotes the story, whereas *Märchenstunde* denotes the session (as does *story time*). While thematically related, I disagree *Gutenachtgeschichte* can be considered a translation of *story time*.

Answer (score -1):

The correct term is

> Märchenstunde

---

### story

(something you can read or tell) can be in German:

- Geschichte
- Artikel
- Mär
- Märchen
- Schwank
- Handlung
- (and some other words)

but *story* also can be (level in a building):

- Geschoß, Geschoss
- Stockwerk
- Etage
- (and some other words)

In this context (a story to be read to a child from a book that contains such stories) it is »**Märchen**« (diminutive of »Mär«, but »Mär« is outdated)

---

### time

This normally is:

- Zeit

So the verbatim translation of *story time* would be:

> Märchenzeit

and you really can use this word in a normal conversation. But

> Märchenstunde

is more common. Both words are correct, and before 1950 *Märchenzeit* was more frequent used than *Märchenstunde*, as you can see in this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=M%C3%A4rchenstunde%2C%20M%C3%A4rchenzeit&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CM%C3%A4rchenstunde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CM%C3%A4rchenzeit%3B%2Cc0)

[image: Ngram Märchenzeit, Märchenstunde]

btw:

Stunde = hour

Comment: Note *Märchenstunde* in German is often used as a sarcastic notion of someone, especially politicians, telling "stories" in public. I checked ngrams and a considerably large amount of hits refers to such usage. Also *Märchenstunde* used to be the title of a comedy series on German TV - Another large amount of hits might refer to this.

Comment: @tofro Both really good points.